# "Optional" ampersand (background-process) in bash

Tags: bash

Given a simple bash script, I would like to have a simple way to make a call of a bash script background task depending on some variable. 
I thought of

```
PARALLEL='&'
./foo.sh $PARALLEL
```

But this does not work as it is probably interpreted as an argument. Is there any possibility (or hack) to make something like that work? Does not have to be clean code...

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is pertinent to understanding the behavior at hand (re: the difference between literal and syntactic content).

Comment: (BTW, lower-case names are appropriate for variables your scripts define; see the relevant POSIX guidelines at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, specifying all-caps names for variables that impact behavior of the operating system or shell and reserving lower-case names for application use -- that spec is on environment variables, but setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, so the convention necessarily applies in both cases).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Safe (and longer) Way

Use an `if`:

```
if [[ ... ]]; then
    ./foo.sh &
else
    ./foo.sh
fi
```

Replace the `...` part with a condition, for instance something like `"$runParallel" = TRUE`.

If your command is longer than just `./foo.sh` it is advisable to wrap it in a function and call that function inside the `if`.

## Unsafe (but shorter) Way

Use `eval`:

```
eval ./foo.sh "$parallel"
```

- In case of `parallel='&'` the command will run in the background.
- In case of `parallel=` the command will run in the foreground and `./foo.sh` has (as desired) no parameter (not even an empty one).
- In case of `parallel='$(rm -rf ~)'` your home directory will be erased :)

Comment: The `eval` approach could be made safer. `run() { local cmd; printf -v cmd '%q '; eval "$cmd ${background+&}"; }` -- `background=1 run foo bar` will run `foo bar` in the background, `run foo bar` will run `foo bar` in the foreground, and it's safe even if `bar` is `'$(rm -rf ~)'`.

Comment: ...one add'l thing to worry about here is that the OP's command is likely to be not something like `./foo.sh`, but something like `./foo.sh "$some_argument"` -- so it's not just an unexpected value in `$parallel` that's dangerous, but an unexpected value in `$some_argument` as well. (And "unexpected" doesn't need to mean "malicious" -- literal quotes that get treated as syntactic ones or such can happen very much by mistake).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the existence of the `$PARALLEL` variable, and call the script accordingly:

```
[[ -n "$PARALLEL" ]] && ( ./foo.sh & ) || ./foo.sh
```

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but you said hacks are fine so I thought I'd offer an alternative.

Comment: This does not work. The `&` is not allowed before `||` or `&&`. You have to start the background job in a subshell: `... && (./foo.sh &) || ...`. Also note that the construct is not equivalent to an if-else. `true && false || echo hello` will *always* print hello.

Comment: To explain *why* what Socowi says is true, `&` is a command separator, just as `;` is -- if you can't legally put `;` somewhere, you can't put a `&` there either.

Comment: (you *could* `{ ./foo & }` legally, and that would avoid runtime overhead for an unnecessary extra subshell, if running on a shell that wouldn't recognize and optimize it out anyhow).